# Does specifying an inline event handler invoke eval()?

Tags: javascript

As mentioned in *JavaScript, The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford, passing a string to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` invokes `eval()`, and should be avoided:

```
setTimeout('console.log("this uses eval()");', 100);
```

With that in mind, does the same thing happen when using inline event handlers, like this?:

```
<button onclick="console.log('click!');">Click Me</button>
```

In other words, does using an inline event handler incur extra parsing overhead when the event is fired, or is the parsing done during the initial document load with everything else (e.g. inline script blocks, scripts in the header, etc).

Comment: I would imagine different browsers handle this in different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, figuratively speaking, it does. *All* javascript in a page is parsed in exactly the same way as code passed to `eval()`. `eval()` is to be avoided, mostly because it is slower than plain code, as it requires an *additional* parse.

You can verify yourself if the browser has already compiled the handler or reparses it, at least for browsers with decent developer tools (example code uses jQuery, but of course you could rewrite it in plain JS):

```
<div id="test" onclick="alert('tested')">Click</div>
<script>
console.log(typeof $('#test')[0].onclick);
console.log($('#test')[0].onclick);
</script>
```

In my Chrome test, this logs the following:

```
Type of handler: function
function onclick(event) {
  alert('click')
}
```

It is obvious that the `onclick` property is a compiled `function` value. You can also see the extra generated code for the handler, namely the function wrapped around the inline code. You can also set a breakpoint in the handler and observe the stack trace to verify that there is no `eval` call anywhere in it.

Comment: +1 but it would be a better answer if you also supplied some links

Comment: See my clarification, I don't think this quite answers the question. Of course the code has to be parsed at some point - that's not what I was asking. I'm assuming that the code passed to setTimeout needs eval() because it's a string literal and doesn't get parsed as code when the document loads, and as such, gets parsed at the time it is called (when the timeout fires).

What I'm asking is if that same pattern happens with inline event handlers, or if those are able to be parsed during the initial load.

Comment: What links would I supply? My answer is simply common sense. The JS parser is the same; in one case the javascript source comes from the actual webpage or from files referenced by `<script>` tags, while in the other case the source comes from a string provided by other javascript code. There would be minor differences (e.g. some local scope for the code executed through the `eval`), but otherwise it is exactly the same.

Comment: @Ianzz as much as I love JavaScript (and appreciate you answering my question), I don't think it's a great idea to assume things about JavaScript because they seem like they're common sense. For example, you'd think it'd be common sense for `arguments` to be an actual array, but it's not. You'd think that `Function.prototype.apply` would be an actual function but guess what? Not in IE. You'd think that a variable declared inside an `if` block wouldn't be available outside that `if` block, but JavaScript is function scoped even though it uses block syntax. Etc, etc...

Comment: It is actually more of an Occam's Razor situation. It would take _much_ effort just to _make it_ seem like the inline handler is _actually_ a compiled function (by providing an _actual_ compiled function instance, which can also be inspected in depth), but still somehow keep it as a _string_ internally just to reparse it on every trigger, for absolutely no reason but to lower the performance of your browser's JS? Of course, I'm only speculating here. I haven't inspected the internals of any browser, but it simply seems like a conspiration theory to assume otherwise :)